# Changing the order of ntile dynamically

Tags: r

Is it possible to change the order of `dplyr::ntile` dynamically using an `ifelse` statement as shown below?

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
y <- "asc"

dat %>% 
  mutate(tile = ntile(ifelse(y == "asc", x, -x), 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `if/else` or even without `if/else` can create this dynamically by changing the logical to binary (by adding 1), select the vector (`c(-1, 1)`) element based on the index i.e. if the index is 2, it selects 1 and if it is 1, it select -1, multiply with 'x', use that as input in `ntile` with `n` specified as 5.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(tile = ntile(c(-1, 1)[1 + (y == 'asc')] * x, 5))
```

-output

```
  x tile
1   1    1
2   2    1
3   3    2
4   4    2
5   5    3
6   6    3
7   7    4
8   8    4
9   9    5
10 10    5
```

---

Changing the 'y' value

```
y <- 'abc'
dat %>%
      mutate(tile = ntile(c(-1, 1)[1 + (y == 'asc')] * x, 5))
```

-output

```
    x tile
1   1    5
2   2    5
3   3    4
4   4    4
5   5    3
6   6    3
7   7    2
8   8    2
9   9    1
10 10    1
```